# Angular2 - ViewChild from a Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a component with the name `EasyBoxComponent`,
and a `@Directive` with this `@Viewchild`:

```js
@ViewChild(EasyBoxComponent) myComponent: EasyBoxComponent;
```

I thought this was the correct syntax, but `this.myComponent` is always undefined.

---

Here's the whole code:

```html
<my-easybox></my-easybox>
<p myEasyBox data-href="URL">My Directive</p>
```

```js
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, HostListener, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { EasyBoxComponent } from '../_components/easybox.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myEasyBox]'
})
export class EasyBoxDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild(EasyBoxComponent) myComponent: EasyBoxComponent;
  @ContentChild(EasyBoxComponent) allMyCustomDirectives;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ViewChild');
    console.log(this.myComponent);
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.altKey);
    console.log(this.myComponent);
    console.log(this.allMyCustomDirectives);
  }
}
```

Comment: where you definer `myComponent` ?

Comment: A directive doesn't have a view, therefore `@ViewChild()` is pointless. Try `@ContentChild()` instead. If it doesn't work, please provide more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: You can't use `ContentChild()` or `@ViewChild()` to query something outside of the component. Only projected content (as the text `MyDirective` is) or direct children within a components view. `<my-easybox>` is a sibling to the element that has the directive. Angular doesn't provide a way to query it. You can use `querySelector` but there are probably better ways. But I would need to understand the actual problem you're trying to solve better to be able to make suggestions.

Comment: I want to make a componet that opens images.... And a directive to add to every image. Every time i click to an image (directive)... I want to send the src to the component to open it

Comment: I will make my component communicate with the directive through service

Answer (score 17):

`ContentChild` works with the `AfterContentInit` interface, so the template should be like:

```html
<p myEasyBox data-href="URL">
   <my-easybox></my-easybox>
</p>
```

and the `@Directive`:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[myEasyBox]'
})
export class EasyBoxDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(EasyBoxComponent) myComponent: EasyBoxComponent;
  @ContentChild(EasyBoxComponent) allMyCustomDirectives;
    
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentInit');
    console.log(this.myComponent);
  }
    
  constructor() {
  }
    
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.altKey);
    console.log(this.myComponent);
    console.log(this.allMyCustomDirectives);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the component is not the child of the directive, the child selector will not work.

Instead, use references:

```html
<my-easybox #myBox></my-easybox>
<p [myEasyBox]="myBox" data-href="URL">My Directive</p>
```

```js
@Input('myEasyBox') myComponent: EasyBoxComponent;
```